# Ken Burns Slideshow Effect Image Size

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

Can someone please explain to me why i can't get the "Ken Burns" effect to show up properly when increasing the size of my images?

I pretty much tried hacking away at this with different images and different CSS settings but I really can't get them stacked and not floating outside the box. It's not interference with my CSS, as I tried it standalone as well.

I would like to have a banner with say a max of 1200x600 that fits the width of the screen. Please provide complete CSS.

https://codepen.io/planetgrafix/pen/erAcF

```
#slideshow {
position:relative;
width:800px;
height:400px;
overflow:hidden;
border:8px solid #ccc;
}

slideshow img {
position:absolute;
width:360px;
height:240px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-left:-180px;
margin-top:-120px;
opacity:0;
snip...
```

https://gist.github.com/pithyless/1861253
Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify? What do you mean by 'show up properly' - can you provide either a screenshot or a codepen/fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: If you change the width and height of the pictures and/or CSS, you can see that the pictures does not fit into the frame anymore, or that they overflow outside the frame. I tried with bigger pictures but that still doesn't help.